# Auto updater JAR

Tags: java, jar, auto-update

I have a JAR file, and I want to be self actualize.

I have so far:

- Step 1: Check if a new vesion.
- Step 2: If there are, download the    "Downloader".
- Step 3: Open the "Downloader", and closes the current    JAR. (HERE IS
  THE PROBLEM).
- Step 4: The "Downloader" replaces the    original JAR.
- Step 5: Open the new JAR.

The problem is, when I open the "Downloader", the current JAR still running.

```
    private void startUpdater() {
    try {

        String command = "java -jar Updater.jar";
        System.out.println("Command: " + command);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        System.out.println("Updater started!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Happy Holidays!

Comment: Can the downloader wait for the original JAR to close?

Comment: If I open the downloader, the current JAR does not close, do not expect anything, if not opened.

Comment: Why don't you close it?

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to have an application core which hardly will ever change and which uses classloaders to deal with jar-files. So you can update the jar at runtime and "replace" the old one with the new one. The only thing to deal with is that all references which are pointing to the old jar (so any class inside the jar) needs to be replaced/updated with the new versions which are available in the new jar.

Comment: The line "exec (command) Runtime.getRuntime ()." JAR waits until the application is closed.

Comment: @Roman Vottner Ok! I will try.

Comment: @RomanVottner You can give me a link?, I'm lost. HH!

Comment: Does this app. have a GUI?  E.G. is it based on something like Swing, Java-FX, SWT, AWT..?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, it´s launcher for a game.

Comment: @Dementor Not sure where you have problems but either google offers plenty of examples on how to deal with classloaders in java or have a look at a [simple plugin framework](https://github.com/RovoMe/PluginApplication) I had to write for a university lecture a couple of years ago.

Comment: The main problem is, when loaded by the class loader, the Jar files are not closed. Yes means that you can not overwrite them. The next problem is that Runtime.exec launches a child process, to means that the current process can not exit until the child process has exited...meaning the jars are still open. What I ended up doing for our app, was write a simple updater that was self contained (it did not use any of the library jars) that was capable of updating the main app, but was also capable of launching childless processes, so it could perform self updates and not leave lots of processes

Answer (score 2):

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, **automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates),** partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or locale, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Answer (score 0):

For those used to Unix, Runtime.exec() is a misnomer. In Unix, exec replaces the current process. In Java, it does not, it, for lack of a better word, "launches" the other process and the process that calls the exec remains.

After exec returns, you have a Process object that acts as a handle to the newly launched process. You don't really need to do anything with this, but you should immediately exit the parent process that

In this case, the process that calls the exec needs to exit as well after the exec has returned, so that the OS doesn't hold the original jar open.